# How to add react components to angular project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I have to add some angular components to angular project and I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react2angular) package.
I did the following steps:

1. `npm install react2angular react react-dom prop-types --save` into the angular project
2. Add a directory (in the root project) named **src** and inside it one index.js with the following code:

   ```
   import { react2angular } from "react2angular";
   import React from "react";

   function Example() {
     return <button type="button">Click me</button>;
   }

   angular
     .module("myModule")
     .component("example", react2angular(Example, ["apiUrl", "token"]));
   ```
3. after this I moved in the angular code and I added

   ```
   <example api-url="123" token="456"/>
   ```

Nothing happens. No button appears.

This seems to be made based on the official documentation.
Did I do something wrong? Keep in mind that I have no experience with angular, this is why I want to work with react.

Comment: Why are you doing an angular project if you want to work only in react ?

Comment: because the angular projec has been made like 5 years ago and I can't do it again because it is super huge.

Comment: can you show where you use myModule? Most likely, your angular module `myModule` is not registered.

Comment: You can't rewrite the app but you can certainly rewrite the component...

Comment: @yadejo it is a fictitious name.. I think I have to put there the name of the module where I am going to use this component, right?

Comment: @Loudrous Yes, correct. is this file imported somewhere? Otherwise, the code wouldn't be bundled and executed

Comment: @yadejo no it is not exported. I only did when you can see in the example code, following the documentation..

Comment: That is the problem. The file -$is never imported anywhere, thus will never be part of the final js bundle.

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Create a React component

    import React from 'react';
    const ReactComponent = ({ fooBar, baz}) => (
      <div>
      <span>value: {fooBar} </span>
      <button onClick={baz}>
        Add one
      </button>
      </div>
     );

   export default ReactComponent;

2. Expose it to Angular

    import { react2angular } from 'react2angular'

    angular
      .module('myModule', [])
      .component('myComponent', react2angular(ReactComponent, ['fooBar', 'baz']))

3. Use it in your Angular 1 code

    <my-component
     foo-bar="3"
     baz="'baz'"
    ></my-component>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react2angular-multiple-modules-cg9zaw?file=angular-component.js

Comment: Thank you! This is right, but in my specific case the problems were different. I had to inject it in my gulp file.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link, by adding wrapper class you can add react component or react npm plugin in to angular project.

https://thalava.com/how-to-use-react-web-components-in-angular.

points to note

1. Add wrapper component in appmodule.ts
2. do npm install after adding react dependencies in package.json